# cordova installtion error occuring

Tags: node.js, cordova, installation

I installed node.js and when I tried to install cordova.Iam getting the following error..

^ Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_mod ules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Please help